# Can I define custom descriptions for Mixins for separate uses with picocli?

Tags: picocli

I have an algorithm with many similar @Options, for instance:

```
@Option(names = {"-if", "--input-file"}, required = true, description = "description")
public void setInputFilePath(String value) throws FileNotFoundException {
    checkInvalidPath(value); // throws FileNotFounException if path does not exist
    inputFile = value;
}
```

I want to make this option a @Mixin, but the problem here is that these options require very different files, so the description I need for the help command differs for each use.
Is it possible to customize the description of a @Mixin option for each use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to solve this with picocli's [support for resource bundles](https://picocli.info/#_internationalization).

You can either have separate resource bundles for each command, or have a shared bundle by pointing each command to the same resource bundle.

Within a shared single resource bundle you can prefix property names with the command name so that an option with the same key can have a different description in different commands.

Example:

```
#MySharedBundle.properties

command1.input-file=description1
command2.input-file=description2
```

Comment: This did the trick! Is it also possible to set alternative default values this way?

Comment: For default values you can use a [default provider](https://picocli.info/#_default_provider). Picocli provides a built-in [properties default provider](https://picocli.info/#_propertiesdefaultprovider) that allows you to specify defaults for multiple commands in a single file.